# Cannot re-use popup-embedded TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, fancybox

I am pulling my hair out over an issue with the popular TinyMCE Editor plugin, embedded inside a Fancybox pop-up window.

I display a list of objects that can be edited, along with Edit links.

When the Edit link is pressed, an AJAX call retrieves content from the server which is placed into a `<textarea>`. A TinyMCE editor is initiated on the fly on this `<textarea>`.

When that pop-up is closed, it triggers a clean-up function.

The very first time this activity is triggered, it works without issue.

All additional attempts fail. The page must be reloaded for TinyMCE to work again as expected.

The result is the TinyMCE editor hidden on the page, textarea object hidden on the page. Even if I am to override visibility/display properties in FireBug, the editor still does not work. (meaning: there is no content displayed in the editor, no carat/cursor displayed, cannot modify the content at all; I can use toolbar buttons but they also do not affect the visible content).

I am using TinyMCE 4.2.4 for jQuery.

This is my TinyMCE editor init/cleanup code:

```
hideEditor = function(){
    tinyMCE.remove('#r_description');
};
loadEditor = function(){
    tinyMCE.init({
        script_url : '/js/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
        selector: "#r_description",
        mode: "none",
        setup :  function(ed) {
            var tinymce_placeholder = $('#'+ed.id);
            var attr = tinymce_placeholder.attr('placeholder');

            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                var is_default = false;

                ed.on('init' , function(ed) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent().replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, '');
                    if(cont.length == 0){
                        ed.target.setContent(tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                        cont = tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder");
                    }

                    is_default = (cont == tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                    if (!is_default){ return; }
                });

                ed.on('focus', function(ed,e) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent().replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, '');
                    is_default = (cont == tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                    if (is_default){
                        ed.target.setContent('');
                    }
                });

                ed.on('blur', function(ed,e) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent();
                    if ( cont == '' ){
                        ed.target.setContent( tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder") );
                    }
                });

            }
        },

        // General options
        theme : "modern",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        toolbar: "link unlink | undo redo",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
        content_css: "/css/wysiwyg.css",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false
    });
}
```

This is the related "Edit" link code:

```
$("a.edit").on( "click", function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if (id != "" ){
        $.get( '/load-' + $ttype + '?d=' + id , function( d ){
            if ( d == 0 ){
            } else {

                $(".edited").find("#r_description").val( d.description );                   
                $.fancybox( "#addResource", {
                    afterLoad: function () { 
                        loadEditor();
                    },
                    beforeClose: function () { hideEditor(); }
                });
            }
        });

    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem. If I understand your correctly, you have the list of links, and each of them should yo open one fancybox with TinyMCE editor.

I done it in [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uogkzp6s/7/) example. But with one hack:

**HTML**

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class="editor" data-descr='test1'>editor 1</div> <br/>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class="editor" data-descr='test2'>editor 2</div> <br/>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class="editor" data-descr='test3'>editor 3</div> <br/>

<div id="TheFancybox" style="display: none;">  
    <textarea id="r_description"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("a.editor").on( "click", function(){
var self = $(this);                   
   $.fancybox( "#TheFancybox", {
       afterLoad: function () { 
           /* loadEditor();
            tinyMCE.get("r_description").execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, self.data('descr')); */
            //tinyMCE initialized here not working correctly   
        },
        afterClose: function () { hideEditor(); }
    });
    //but if you init it here - it will

    $('#r_description').val(self.data('descr')); 
    loadEditor();

    return false;
});

function hideEditor(){
    tinyMCE.remove('#r_description');
};

function loadEditor(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#r_description",
        mode: "none",
        setup :  function(ed) {
            var tinymce_placeholder = $('#'+ed.id);
            var attr = tinymce_placeholder.attr('placeholder');

            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                var is_default = false;

                ed.on('init' , function(ed) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent().replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, '');
                    if(cont.length == 0){
                        ed.target.setContent(tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                        cont = tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder");
                    }

                    is_default = (cont == tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                    if (!is_default){ return; }
                });

                ed.on('focus', function(ed,e) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent().replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, '');
                    is_default = (cont == tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder"));
                    if (is_default){
                        ed.target.setContent('');
                    }
                });

                ed.on('blur', function(ed,e) {
                    var cont = ed.target.getContent();
                    if ( cont == '' ){
                        ed.target.setContent( tinymce_placeholder.attr("placeholder") );
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        // General options
        theme : "modern",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        toolbar: "link unlink | undo redo",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
        content_css: "/css/wysiwyg.css",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false
    });
}
```

I hope it help you to solve your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU! Taking loadEditor outside of afterLoad worked!! :}